# how to re-encode data from CFFTPCreateParsedResourceListing function?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

i try to communicate with FTP server using CFNetwork.framework.

using CFFTP API(CFWriteStreamCreateWithFTPURL function), i get a NSData of specific URL.

then i start to parse the NSData with CFFTPCreateParsedResourceListing function, it gives me poorly encoded filenames.(when the file name is Korean)
all character in Korean is converted to question mark(?).

how can i fix this? please give me some advice. thank you in advance.

---

```
NSMutableArray *    newEntries;
NSUInteger          offset;

newEntries = [NSMutableArray array];
assert(newEntries != nil);

offset = 0;
do {
    CFIndex         bytesConsumed;
    CFDictionaryRef thisEntry;

    thisEntry = NULL;

    assert(offset <= [self.listData length]);
    bytesConsumed = CFFTPCreateParsedResourceListing(NULL, &((const uint8_t *) self.listData.bytes)[offset], (CFIndex) ([self.listData length] - offset), &thisEntry);
    if (bytesConsumed > 0) {

        if (thisEntry != NULL) {
            NSDictionary *  entryToAdd;

            entryToAdd = [self entryByReencodingNameInEntry:(__bridge NSDictionary *) thisEntry encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

            [newEntries addObject:entryToAdd];
        }


        offset += (NSUInteger) bytesConsumed;
    }

    if (thisEntry != NULL) {
        CFRelease(thisEntry);
    }

    if (bytesConsumed == 0) {

        break;
    } else if (bytesConsumed < 0) {

        [self stopReceiveWithStatus:@"Listing parse failed"];
        break;
    }
} while (YES);
```

---

### below code is entryByReencodingNameInEntry method

```
NSDictionary *  result;
NSString *      name;
NSData *        nameData;
NSString *      newName;

newName = nil;

// Try to get the name, convert it back to MacRoman, and then reconvert it
// with the preferred encoding.

name = [entry objectForKey:(id) kCFFTPResourceName];
if (name != nil) {
    assert([name isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]);

    nameData = [name dataUsingEncoding:NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding];
    if (nameData != nil) {
        newName = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:nameData encoding:newEncoding];
    }
}

if (newName == nil) {
    assert(NO);                 // in the debug builds, if this fails, we should investigate why
    result = (NSDictionary *) entry;
} else {
    NSMutableDictionary *   newEntry;

    newEntry = [entry mutableCopy];
    assert(newEntry != nil);

    [newEntry setObject:newName forKey:(id) kCFFTPResourceName];

    result = newEntry;
}

return result;
```

---

for example,
if a folder has 3 files
애플.txt, 삼성.txt, 테스트.txt -> converted to ??.txt, ??.txt, ???.txt

Comment: Please post your code and more information about what precise problems you are running into and what your desired results are.

Comment: i just post additional code for more precise information. how was it?

Comment: Your code helped. I did some digging, and it looks like your FTP server might only support ASCII. They can basically pick whatever encoding they want. See https://github.com/karelia/ConnectionKit/issues/41